# Git: Turn current master into branch and keep uncommitted changes

Tags: git

I'm working on my current master and have done quite a few changes which are as of now neither locally nor remotely committed. However, I am ready to commit them. Before doing so I would like to turn the current master without these uncommitted changes into a new branch but I am not completely sure what the right procedure for this is. My first idea was to do a clean clone in a different directory

```
git clone REPO
```

and then initialize 
a new branch from the current master

```
git checkout -b OLD_MASTER
```

and then commit. Then go back into the other clone which contains the uncommitted changes and commit them. But that seems unclean to me. What is the right way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I must ask, why do you need this? Git maintains history of the master branch for you, and if you need to revert, you should revert back to that commit. You should also look into [tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) so you can version your releases properly.

Comment: I know, I'm just for failsafe redundancy. Also, I might have to have the current master available extremely fast without reverting commits first.

Comment: "turn the current master [...] into a branch" doesn't really make sense, because `master` already *is* a branch. Also doing `git checkout -b OLD_MASTER` and then committing will make `OLD_MASTER` point to a new commit which has nothing to do with the old `master`, so that doesn't make sense either. I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve here; please could you clarify the use case or end goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the branch and go back to master:

```
git stash
git checkout -b old_master
git checkout master
git stash pop
```

But don't you want a `tag` instead?

```
git tag old_master
```

Comment: The stash is redundant.  You only need the `git checkout -b new_branch`.

Comment: @AdamSpiers "I would like to turn the current master without these uncommitted changes into a branch" meaning OP doesn't want the changes to come into the new branch.

Comment: I've edited but I'm still not sure I got the full problem. It might be a tag is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the tag-reminder @sjagr and Fancis Colas. I used that as well as the stash-based solution.

Comment: @sjagr `git checkout -b new_branch` won't put the changes in the new branch; they'll still only be in the working tree.

Comment: @FrancisColas Why do you think the stash commands are necessary here?

Comment: Not necessary, I agree; but useful in the case where you want to pull changes from a remote (which you'd do once you're back on `master`).

Comment: @FrancisColas Sorry, I have no clue what you mean. I'm talking about the 4 commands you listed above, which have nothing to do with pulling changes from a remote, and would have exactly the same effect if you dropped the two stash commands.  Additionally the two `checkout` commands could be replaced by a single command: `git branch old_master`.